# How to get external IP Address?

Tags: java, android

I recently started a chat app that works with Firebase Auth & Database,
now for security reasons **I want to save their IP's on the Database**...not their local one (192.168...), I want to save their **external** (91.22....). I'll **add this aswell to the GDPR** but I don't know the code for that.

Is there a short Java Source Code?
like "android.os. ..." Code?

I also tried some else codes but it did not worked aswell.

I appreciate ya' answers :)

Comment: You could do a cURL request to a public IP API

Comment: And just for the record: that IP might change rather quickly sometimes. So be careful for what you intend to use it. You can't use the IP as primary identification property (if that is what you have in mind).

Comment: There is no such thing as a device **IP** address. Are you talking about the MAC address? And note: when you want to respond to a specific other user, use @+userid to do so.

Comment: `Device IP that can't change` there is no such `IP`. Any IP can change. You are probably talking about the `MAC` address, but it can change also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a socket you can do `socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()`

If you want the device you get it's own public IP address, you can use this method:

```
URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream()));
String ip = in.readLine(); //IP as a string
System.out.println(ip);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a short Java Source Code?

No.

> like "android.os. ..." Code?

No. The device does not necessarily know its external IP address, just like a desktop or notebook does not necessarily know its external IP address.

Make a request of your Web service, and have your Web service note what IP address the request comes from.